# SQL - Insert INTO results in nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to get this INSERT to work correctly, so I worked through the undefined variable and index problems and now I think I am nearly there.

Below is the code:

---

```
<?php
session_start();
require "../dbconn.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$query1 = "SELECT user_table.user_id FROM user_table  WHERE user_table.username ='".$username."'";    

$query2 = "SELECT department.department_id FROM department, user_table, inventory
       WHERE user_table.user_id = department.user_id
       AND department.department_id = inventory.department_id";

//Copy the variables that the form placed in the URL
//into these three variables
$item_id = NULL;
$category = $_GET['category'];
$item_name = $_GET['item_name'];
$item_description = $_GET['item_description'];
$item_quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
$item_quality = $_GET['quality'];
$item_status = NULL;
$order_date = $_GET['order_date'];
$invoice_attachment = NULL;
$edit_url = 'Edit'; 
$ordered_by = $username;
$user_id = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$department_id = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
$price = $_GET['price'];
$vat = $_GET['vat%'];
$vat_amount = $_GET['vat_amount'];
$create_date = date("D M d, Y G:i");
$change_date = NULL;

//set up the query using the values that were passed via the URL from the form
$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO inventory (item_id, category, item_name, item_description, item_quantity, item_quality, item_status, order_date,
invoice_attachment, edit_url, ordered_by, user_id, department_id, price,     vat, vat_amount, create_date, change_date VALUES(
'".$item_id."',
'".$category."',
'".$item_name."',
'".$item_description."',
'".$item_quantity."',
'".$item_quality."',
'".$item_status."',
'".$order_date."',
'".$invoice_attachment."',
'".$edit_url."',
'".$ordered_by."',
'".$user_id."',
'".$department_id."',
'".$price."',
'".$vat."',
'".$vat_amount."',
'".$create_date."',
'".$change_date."')")
or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
header( 'Location:../myorders.php');
?>
```

Error:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES( '', 'adasd', 'dsadsa', 'dsad', 'sadsad', '' at line 2

Could anyone please let me know where I am going wrong? :(

Been staring at this for 3-5 hours already :(

Comment: Can you please paste the result of a die(var_dump($query)); ?

Comment: You have not specified the columns where to insert your values... and for the record, consider using mysqli_* or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_* API.

Comment: You need to *execute* the query... that is, throw `$query` into `mysql_query`.

Comment: `mysql_query($query);` ^

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually trying to **insert** any data into your table. You only craft and assign the **query** in string form to a variable. You need to use the function [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to actually run the code.

As pointed out you will also have to specify the columns you are inserting data into in the MySQL query if you don't supply data for every column (in the correct order). Here you can look at the [MySQL insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

I would also urge you to look into using the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or the [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions for communicating with your MySQL database since the MySQL extension is deprecated. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for additional information and comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you only assign the values to the $query var:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (
'".$item_id."',
'".$category."',
'".$item_name."',
'".$item_description."',
'".$quantity."',
'".$quality."',
'".$item_status."',
'".$order_date."',
'".$invoice_attachment."',
'".$edit_url."',
'".$ordered_by."',
'".$price."',
'".$vat."',
'".$vat_amount."',
'".$create_date."',
'".$change_date."')"
or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

You do not actually run the query.

try:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO inventory (column_name1, column_name 2, column_name3 ... the column name for each field you insert) VALUES (
    '".$item_id."',
    '".$category."',
    '".$item_name."',
    '".$item_description."',
    '".$quantity."',
    '".$quality."',
    '".$item_status."',
    '".$order_date."',
    '".$invoice_attachment."',
    '".$edit_url."',
    '".$ordered_by."',
    '".$price."',
    '".$vat."',
    '".$vat_amount."',
    '".$create_date."',
    '".$change_date."')")
    or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Also, you should use mysqli_* or any other PDO as the mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: That won't work as he is not specifying values for all columns "I do have a few extra fields in the SQL table - but those are foreign key fields so they are not included."

Answer (score 0):

If you are not inserting in all columns you need to specify the columns you are going to insert. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table(Column1, Column6) VALUES (Value1, Value6)
```

You are missing the column names in your INSERT

Comment: and where is the table name?

Comment: Added, forget about it!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've updated the INSERT INTO part of the script and now at least I am getting some errors and I can see some of the data into from the forms into the error codes! :)

Comment: I now get this error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ( '', 'asdas', 'sasda', 'sasdas', 'dsa', 'a' at line 2

I suspect it is because I have no accounted for the Foreign key fields in the Inventory table.

I have the following extra fields:

item_id (Primary key of the inventory table)

user_id (Foreign key field from user_table)

department_id (Foreign key field from the department table)

Comment: I set the extra fields that were missing to NULL Variables and included them in the INSERT part so it should not cause any problems meaning that all columns are accounted for in the INSERT but I still get the same error :(

Comment: Can you paste the complete $sqlQuery string so we can see what is actually being executed in the query?

Comment: I've added it to the question  :)

Comment: No, you still are showing how you build the query string. I want to see the result of all that concatenations as a string, without all that quotes madness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72780/discussion-between-justin-and-juan).